# A simple question about vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that we have a vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^3$ whose components are $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3).$

> **Question.** It is possible to see the vector $v$ as a vector of $\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}$? That is $v=((v_1,v_3),v_2)$, or $v=((v_2,v_3),v_1)$?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes of course, the isomorphisms are obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In particular, we can identify $((v_1,v_2),v_3)\in\mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R$ with the vector $(v_1,v_2,v_3)\in\mathbb R^3$. You should check that this is an isomorphism so that the operations in the vector space work normally, and once you have done that, you can safely treat them as the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your ansewer. The isomorphism you exhibited is seen as a natural thing. (although it should always be rigorously proved). But the same thing happens for example if $((v_2,v_3),v_1)$ and for $((v_1,v_3),v_2)$?

Comment: @JackJ. How does that matter? You are just calling the same thing new names.